# Projecting a vector on orthogonal planes

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, projective-space

I am looking from an engineer point of view. I have a sensor for which I need vector projecting on two different planes.
I have the unit vector in the body frame that is to be projected and I obtained that using the rotation matrix. Also I have the unit vectors of the frame which is formed by the three planes. 
If {**n1, n2, t**} represents those three unit vectors and **s** gives me the unit vector measured in body frame, how can I obtain projection of **s** on **n1,t** and **n2,t** plane.

Comment: Are the vectors orthogonal?

Comment: yes {n1 n2 t } form orthogonal triad but the only information about s is that its a unit vector in that frame

Comment: Then, for example, the projection onto the $n_1,t$ plane is given by $s-\langle n_2,s\rangle n_2$. This just subtracts off the component in the $n_2$ direction.

Comment: so it is **s**-dot(**n2**,**s**) x**n2**?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the vectors n1, n2, and t are mutually orthogonal, the projection of s onto the n1,t plane is "s - (s*n2)n2", that is, find the projection of s onto n2, the normal to the n1,t plane, and subtract it from s. Similarly, the projection onto the n2,t plane would be "s - (s*n1)n1". This is not a change of coordinate system, if that is what you wanted. If that is what you wanted, you can obtain the coordinates in the n1, n2 and t directions by dotting the unit vectors with s, i.e. "s = s_i * e_i' = s * e_i" where s_i is the component of s in the e_i direction and e_i belongs to {n1,n2,t}.